# How to count xcassets subdirectory images

Tags: ios, ios7

Is there a way to count the images in a Xcassets subdirectory?

IE, I want to display for each image in a subdirectory in Images.xcassets an UICollectionViewCell to display the image.

Comment: Ever figure this out?